# Re-run Pixel 4 Setup

Tags: google-pixel, setup-wizard

My girlfriend just purchased a Pixel 4 from Verizon. Apparently, the Verizon representative rushed through the initial setup flow, and my girlfriend didn't get a chance to configure her phone the way she wanted. Is it possible to re-run the onboarding flow?

Comment: I think everything that can be configured through initial setup wizard is also available in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** familiar with ADB environment, then the **most suitable solution** for you is to **Factory Reset** your device. However, if you are familiar with ADB, then follow this:

```
adb shell su
pm enable com.google.android.setupwizard/com.google.android.setupwizard.SetupWizardActivity

adb shell settings put secure user_setup_complete 0
```

> Please note that the commands are case-sensitive and require
>   permissions.